# Ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: python, синтаксис

Помогите пожалуйста исправить код. В 11 строке выдает ошибку синтаксиса. Пытаюсь написать программу для угадывания чисел.
При вводе:

> «game»

должна запускаться игра

> «Угадай число»
>
> (правильный ответ – 5)

Для ответа даётся три попытки. Если дан правильный ответ, то печатается:

> «Вы выиграли билет на концерт!»

В игру можно сыграть любое число раз. При вводе «`off`» программа должна завершать работу.

```
#Начать игру(не работает если в коде есть y=x)
x="game"
y=input("Введите game чтобы начать")
if y==x:
    print("Введите число от 1 до 10. У вас есть 3 попытки")
else:
    print("Всего вам хорошего")
#Сама игра
answer=5
var=int(input("Ваш вариант?")
tries == 2
while var != answer:
    if tries == 0:
        break
    var=int(input("Ваш вариант?"))
    tries -= 1
    
#Система побед и поражений
if var =! answer:
    print("Вы ничего не получаете")
else:
    print("Вы выиграли билет в театр")
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых в строке `var=int(input("Ваш вариант?")` не хватает закрывающей скобки.

Во-вторых `tries == 2` вы должны записать так `tries = 2` так как знак `==` является оператором сравнения, в то время `=` присваивает значение указанной переменной.

Ну и в-третьих в `if var =! answer: print("Вы ничего не получаете")` неправильно указали оператор неравенства, должно быть `!=`

Answer (score -1):

```
y=input("Введите game чтобы начать")
if y=='game':
    i = 3
    answer = 5
    while i > 0:
      ask = int(input("Введите число от 1 до 10. У вас есть 3 попытки"))
      if ask == answer:
        print('Вы выиграли!')
        break
      else:
        print('Увы!')
        i-=1
else:
    print("Всего вам хорошего")
```

Comment: так не объяснили почему ошибка. афтор и дальше её будет допускать

Comment: если надо разберется